# How to remove empty lists from a list and extract values using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove empty list and extra [] around elements

```
Input: data = [[1], [], [2], [], [], [4]];
Expected: output = [1,2,4]
```

When I do this : `d = [x for x in data if x]`
I have an output with [] around elements as below:

```
[[1], [2], [4]]
```

Appreciate if someone can help!

Comment: You just want to *flatten* the list, empty sublists will vanish in the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain(*data)))
```

Comment: `chain(*data)` -> `chain.from_iterable(data)`